# Why can't I use PineMap to store a referential cons-list? Getting "still borrowed" error even after end of main

Tags: rust, ownership, rust-pin

Why does this code:

```rs
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd)]
enum List<'a> {
    Cons(isize, &'a List<'a>),
    Nil,
}

fn main() {
    use List::*;
    use pinus::{prelude::*, sync::PineMap};
    let table = PineMap::new();
    table.insert(Nil, Nil);
    let nil = table.get(&Nil).unwrap();
    table.insert(Cons(1, nil), Cons(1, nil));
}
```

cause this error:

```
error[E0597]: `table` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:15
   |
12 |     let nil = table.get(&Nil).unwrap();
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
13 |     table.insert(Cons(1, nil), Cons(1, nil));
14 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `table` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `table` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `PineMap`
```

I'm using a [`pinus::sync::PineMap`](https://docs.rs/pinus/latest/pinus/sync/struct.PineMap.html) to try to make sure that all references to equivalent instances of `List` are actually references of the same object in memory. I thought a way to do this would be to have a table mapping `List` keys to a table-owned instance of `List`, and I'm trying out `PineMap` for it because its `insert` will not move its items in memory (its insert borrows `&self` not `&mut self` too) so references to its `List` values will stay valid, and I can build self-referential items.

Why is `table` still considered to be borrowed at the end of its scope in my code?

Answer (score 1):

When you get `nil` out of the table and put it back into it with `Cons(1, nil)`, the type of `nil` is a reference that is tied to the lifetime of the `table`, and thus the lifetime `'a` of the `List`s that you're storing are bound to the `table` that is storing them.

The core problem here is that this creates a self-referential struct, which introduces a myriad of problems. You wouldn't be able to call any of the mutable methods either because the `table` is permanently borrowing itself immutably.

The specific problem that the compiler is complaining about is that, since the elements hold a reference to the table, when its being dropped the drop logic may try to access data that is in the process of being destroyed, which is not sound.

I encourage you to read about the [Drop Check](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dropck.html) in the Rustonomicon for more info, here's a guiding principle though:

> For a generic type to soundly implement drop, its generics arguments must strictly outlive it.

I don't have any workarounds or solutions for you other than you can't do it this way.

Comment: Please can you help me understand why making a new scope just for nil doesn't work either?  I asked a new question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74644342/3310334